# SIGABRT ERROR for a single IBAction and IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am extremely new to XCode and Swift so would prefer any answers to be as simple as possible :)

I get the following when i try to run the app:[1]: (So the app just crashed pretty much :P) https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtZfR.png

The Main.storyboard is : [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYv5.png

I think the problem (from viewing other stackexchange/overflow posts) is from deleting IBActions/Outlets. In the previous images, I have added and deleted IBActions/Outlets from the ViewController and Main.Storyboard. I have tried restarting XCode but it does not help. All I want is so that the app doesn't crash! How do I get rid of this error (using as simple language as possible please) Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you attach complete crash logs image or crash log, currently the crash image attached by you is showing only last line.

Comment: Please post any affected code as text, not an image. You're more likely to get this issue looked at if people can view your code in a textual form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have delete any outlet or action which was connected with button or your any object then remove it's reference from `connection inspector`. Select your button from interface builder (story board) and ope connection inspector and press `(x)` to deleted outlets or action. I am attaching screenshot,

[image]

Here you can see referencing outlet. you can delete it by pressing cross button if you have multiple outlet or deleted outlet or action

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting so frustrated with this! Lifesaver :)    ---   also rishi and Draken, I will keep in mind your comments for next time